# Does .NET SelectNodes() allow you to select attributes?

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, selectnodes

Does it pull all node types supported by Xpath? Seems that when I call

selectNodes("@")

it just returns the elements that contain the attributes, but I want to get the list of attributes themselves. In other words I would expect the resulting node collection to contain nodes of type Attr only...but that does not seem to work.

Comment: What happens, when you use `SelectNodes("@*")`?

Comment: Check my answer for the correct syntax and an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

foreach(XmlAttribute att in selectNodes("****/@****"))
  ...

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

> Selects a list of nodes matching the
>   XPath expression.

While the Attributes property (of a Node)

> Gets an XmlAttributeCollection
>   containing the attributes of this
>   node.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx

To get all attributes in a document (I think that's what you're trying to do?) you may want to try

selectNodes("@*")

Comment: This doesn't really answer his question, because `XmlAttribute` derives from `XmlNode`.

Comment: @Daniel, I've updated my answer since you commented. I was in the midst of editing it because I think I figured out what he was trying to do.

Comment: Right, as @Daniel suggests, Attribute is just another XMLNodeType...I would expect you to be able to return a collection of attributes via SelectNodes()...certainly using the Xpath suggested from @Shiv, but I still can't get it to return a collection. Just trying to figure out if SelectNodes() will return attributes in addition to elements.

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath syntax for selecting **context node**'s attributes is:

```
@*
```

Or

```
attribute::*
```

**But do note that only elements might have attributes**. So, if the context node is the document root, you won't select anything, of course.

If you want **all the attributes from a document**, use:

```
//@*
```

That will be expanded to:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/attribute::*
```